# how to make a discord bot that copies the usernames with the ID?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I need help. I want to make a discord bot that copies the usernames with the ID and sends it as a text file in the second. I tried to do that, but to no avail.

Example:
Username: ID used

```
if (message.content === '16') {
 if (!devs.includes(message.author.id)) return;
 if (message.channel.type === "dm") return;

client.on("message", (message) => {
   if (message.channel.type === "dm") {
     if (message.author.id != client.user.id) {
       let yumz = new Discord. ( guild.members.username, guild.members.id)
       client.channels.find(e=>e.id === '75759********20').send(file.txt);

     }       
   }
 });
```

Comment: How did you try this before? Please put that attempt in.

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
    https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
    How To Ask Questions The Smart Way
    https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask
    Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example
    http://sscce.org/

    How To Ask Questions The Smart Way
    http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: critical skill for anyone who hopes to be a valuable problem solver is to chop up the problem into smaller problems then chop those into yet smaller until you have bite sized solvable nuggets ... number two skill is to grow your frustration tolerance

Comment: I added it, I know it's a mistake, but I'm new to this, and thank you for your reply @MrMythical

Answer (score 4):

To send a text file, you simply [`send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) a [`MessageFile`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageFile):

```js
// get the text content to send as a file
const text = `${message.author.username}: ${message.author.id}`;

// create the message file data
const MessageFile = {
  attachment: Buffer.from(text)
};

// Send the file!
channel.send({
  files: [MessageFile]
});
```

This answer assumes the latest `discord.js` version (v13).